# A/B Testing with support of Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: appcelerator, ab-testing, appcelerator-titanium, abtest

I would like to know if there is any reasonably good platform for A/B testing that supports Appcelerator Titanium?  So far I have not been lucky in finding one.

Answer (score 0):

How about [vessel](https://vessel.readme.io/docs/titanium). It supports Titanium.

Comment: Hi, Shawn! I´ve seen this, but I got confused. Vessel was bought by Marketo, and in the documentation of Marketo, I see nothing about Titanium. Could you explain me better where I can find pricing information and registration form for Vessel?

Comment: I have contacted Marketo, and they discontinued Titanium support, so this one is out of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Look at a company named "Tune", they offer some great mobile analytics.

https://www.tune.com/#asa

> A/B test app store descriptions to drive higher install rates
>
> A/B test push notifications, messaging, features, and navigation flow

Comment: I am looking for a platform that supports Titanium. If we do have to go without out of the box Titanium support (that is, I'll have to write the module), we already have some candidates available